# Wheel animation in rounded shape

Tags: android, animation

I am new in android. I want to make rounded wheel animation type animation for my application home page like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ShareBuilderMobile.android&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIlNoYXJlQnVpbGRlck1vYmlsZS5hbmRyb2lkIl0), any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "**3D carousel view**". We don't have much examples based on that. But still here is a very good link which has the source code for this sample.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

But still you have to roll out things to make the changes and customize it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below links its help to how to implement this functionality(Cover Flow)

http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html